# Query Oracle to join date interval in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, range

my question is join more date interval in one if start of second row is the day after the end of first row. In all these case I should have one row only.
ex:

```
id      start           end
10      20120101        20120125
10      20120201        20120225
10      20120226        20120302
10      20120303        20120304
```

must be

```
10      20120101        20120125
10      20120201        20120304
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my suggestion: is you have these rows in a table, let's call it "temp_table", you can create a view in which you keep only the dates that are relevant:

```
CREATE VIEW temp_view AS
SELECT id, dd, ROWNUM AS nr
  FROM (
    SELECT s.ID, s.start_date AS dd --for izolated intervals, keep the wtart date
      FROM temp_table s, temp_table prv, temp_table nxt
     WHERE prv.end_date(+) = s.start_date-1 AND prv.ID(+) = s.ID
       AND s.end_date+1 = nxt.start_date(+) AND nxt.ID(+) = s.ID
       AND prv.ID IS NULL AND nxt.ID IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT s.ID, decode(nxt.id, 
                   NULL, s.end_date, --no next interval => keep the end date
                   decode(prv.id,
                      NULL, s.start_date)  --no previous interval => keep the start date
                  ) AS dd 
      FROM temp_table s, temp_table prv, temp_table nxt
     WHERE prv.end_date(+) = s.start_date-1 AND prv.ID(+) = s.ID
       AND s.end_date+1 = nxt.start_date(+) AND nxt.ID(+) = s.ID
       AND (prv.ID IS NULL OR nxt.ID IS NULL)
    ORDER BY dd   --order all the dates ascending  
  );
```

This view will return something like this:

```
ID  DD          NR
10  20120101    1
10  20120125    2
10  20120201    3
10  20120304    4
```

And you can query something like:

```
SELECT start_dates.ID, start_dates.dd AS start_date, end_dates.dd AS end_date
  FROM temp_view start_dates, temp_view end_dates 
 WHERE start_dates.ID = end_dates.ID
   AND start_dates.nr+1 = end_dates.nr 
   AND MOD(start_dates.nr,2) = 1
```

The result:

```
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE
10  20120101    20120125
10  20120201    20120304
```